# Probability for a lottery

Tags: probability, lotteries

What's probability to choose the 6 correct numbers in a lottery (made up of 42 numbers)?
I do know how to do it with combinatorics
$${42 \choose 6}  
= (42·41·40·39·38·37)\div ( 1·2·3·4·5·6)
= 502450786$$

but how can you get the answer reasoning fully explained?

Comment: What do you mean by "Classic probability"? To me combinatorics is a part of probability.

Comment: @QthePlatypus The answer by brams is as what I think could be classic probability. Not too sure though because it is a rough translation from german.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you computed the number of sets of $6$ numbers of $42$. Each of these outcomes is equally probable, and hence the *probability* of you picking exactly the one that's drawn is therefore:

$$\frac{1}{{42 \choose 6}}=\frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6}{42 \cdot 41 \cdot 40 \cdot 39 \cdot 38 \cdot 37}$$

You can also get this as follows. You need to have the first number that's drawn, and since you picked $6$ numbers, the probability of that is $\frac{6}{42}$. Ok, but after you get the first one correct, you also need the second one correct, and since you have $5$ numbers left, and there are still $41$ numbers left that can be chosen, the probability of that is $\frac{5}{41}$. But now you likewise also need the third number correct, the fourth, fifth, and sixth, and so the probability to get them all is:

$$\frac{6}{42} \cdot \frac{5}{41} \cdot \frac{4}{40} \cdot \frac{3}{39} \cdot \frac{2}{38} \cdot \frac{1}{37}$$

... which is of course the same as the above.